# iOS Contstraints Cause SIGABRT Error

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am making constraints with the visual language, but whenever I try to add them it causes an error.

```
class TimerViewController : UIViewController{
    let timer = TimerView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(timer)
        self.createContraints()
    }

    func createContraints(){
        self.timer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraints = 
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[timer]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["timer" : timer])
        let verticleContraints = 
NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|==[timer]==|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["timer" : timer])
        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
        self.view.addConstraints(verticleContraints)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this in code? In most cases, it's far simpler to do this sort of thing in interface builder and is less error prone.

Comment: I agree with @Brandon , you dont need to add == here, if you see your console there you will see error like this  ` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Expected a view 
V:|==[v0]==| 
   ^' 
`  , which tells you what is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode gives you the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Expected a view 
V:|==[timer]==| 
   ^'
```

So remove the == and it will work.

Comment: Even if I remove the ==, it still crashes

Comment: @Snifferdog it doesn't. I ran the same code without both ==. Read your errors in Xcode console/log.

Comment: Yea, I thought I tried it without that constraint, but it just worked. Thank you.